# Error CS1684: Reference to type with json.NET framework with xamarin iOS

Tags: c#, ios, json.net, xamarin

I have the last release of the dll and the last ios xamarin version downloaded checked just now and after trying a lot of stuffs i came to this error and i dont know what do to anymore.

Error CS1684: Reference to type `System.Dynamic.IDynamicMetaObjectProvider' claims it is defined assembly`System.Core, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e', but it could not be found (CS1684) (CartaDeVinhos)

I have 2 applications, one in android and the other in iOS.
Android works just fine i get this error with iOS.

Here's the site http://james.newtonking.com/json

So i really dont know what to try anymore and i really need this working so if anyone know anything i would be really thankful.

Bye

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the .NET version number under which the application is being build also the app.config file for the version expected.

This might be of your interest: [Could not load file or assembly 'System.Core, Version=2.0.5.0](http://forums.asp.net/t/1731868.aspx)

Comment: How do i chech on mac OS which version of .net i have and where do i find this app.config file?

Comment: I ended up using the json.net with the dll mobile 4.0 and it worked its the only dll that works on ios